# HHVM and PHP exec()

Tags: php, permissions, exec, hhvm

I'm trying to use the exec() PHP function on a system that run on HHVM.

Unfortunately, the command (even a simple echo) return an empty string, without any error. When I try the command inside terminal as root the output is correct.

PHP Safe mode is off, I guess this is a permission issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you show some code, including specifically how you're executing PHP on the command-line?

Comment: echo exec(echo Hello); and echo exec(whoami);

Answer (score 2):

I've updated HHVM to 3.x, and it's now working like a charm.